# How long it takes to find my Google+ profile through Google+ Rest API

Tags: rest, google-api, google-plus, google-api-client, google-apis-explorer

I created an application as part of a university project that searches using web APIs. Google+ is one of the APIs considered.

Now I am trying to evaluate this application against what other search tools offer. In the evaluation, I ask the user to create a google plus account and then try to find it using the search engine example.com and then try our tool.

The problem I am having is that when I create a google plus profile, I can not find it immediately using "Google+ API people search". Is there a way to tell the API to consider recently created profiles or any other solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

No. Google+ is a large application and things can take time to process by various other systems.